# Ionic framework and bottom fixed content

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a simple page with a login form (user/password text input + 1 button). I would like to fix this form to the bottom of a ion-content. But it does not work.

HTML:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content padding="true">

    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpeg" />

    <div class="login-form">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input light-text-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="user" ng-model="user">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input light-text-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="password" ng-model="password">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="button button-block button-energized">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="button button-block button-positive">FB Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="text-center"><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Forgot password</a></p>
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

I would like to set as "fixed" the div.login-form.

Using the following CSS does not work:

```
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Also, with position:fixed input texts seem no more editable.

In Ionic, is it possible to fix part of the content to bottom?
Thx!

Answer (score 36):

You could use anythnig out the `ion-content` with a button inside of it.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/cnqfL)

```
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              href="#/item/{{item.id}}">
      Item {{ item.id }}

    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>

<div class="fixed-outside">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-circle button-energized icon ion-log-in"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-circle button-positive icon ion-social-facebook"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-center"><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Forgot password</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need: I would like to fix to bottom the entire form, not just a row of labels/buttons. I tried to place everything inside a ion-footer-bar, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: But it is not unusable way. For small app it is good but for larg with module structure it take mach more efforts to controll and make more difficalt add  independent plugin at exists app

Comment: In case of an input putting it out of ion-content would cause the keyboard to cover the input

Answer (score 6):

How about just using the default ionic tab bar and just change the height to auto or any px that you wishes. Just make sure you put the code below ion-content tag.

Code:

```
<ion-content padding="true">
</ion-content>  
  <div class="tabs tabs-dark" style="height:auto;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
            <input type="text">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" >
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive">LOGIN</button>                         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Codepen example : http://codepen.io/ridwan/pen/JozeYK

Answer (score 5):

You could use a directive to calculate the height of the form. It will recalculate on window resize. I haven't tested navigating away from the page.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/OPqRyL)

Relevant HTML

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-content padding="true" scroll="false">
    <ion-scroll scroll-height>
       Content to go above the form
    </ion-scroll>
    <div class="login-form">
      Login form
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

CSS

```
.scroll-content {
  position: relative;
}

div.login-form {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Directive

```
.directive('scrollHeight', function($window) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.onResize = function() {
        var winHeight = $window.innerHeight;
        var form = angular.element(document.querySelector('.login-form'))[0];
        var formHeight = form.scrollHeight;
        var scrollHeight = winHeight - formHeight;

        element.css("height", scrollHeight + "px");
      }
      scope.onResize();

      angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        scope.onResize();
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really expected that Ionic handled this on its own somehow.

Answer (score 4):

all the elements which you want to have fixed  in the bottom should be out of the  `ion-content`. This is a working  example:

```
<ion-view title="Test" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content class="padding">
   <img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpeg" />
</ion-content>

<!-- align to the bottom of the page -->
  <div class="login-form" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input light-text-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="user" ng-model="user">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input light-text-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="password" ng-model="password">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-block button-energized">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive">FB Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-center"><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Forgot password</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've put this into a fiddle. Is this what you're expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9hz8pbem/1/

Comment: I'm not sure why that's better, but I've fixed your broken image again so we can see what's happening: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JozbRg  There seems to be no scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I just find a simple solution, which works fine for me.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll style="height: 300px">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
        your scroll content
    </div>>
    </ion-scroll>
    <div>
        your fixed div, maybe a form
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

you can also refer to: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution as if the page is more or less than 1000px it won't go to the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up more or less circumventing Ionic's intentions and using a flex box layout:

```
<ion-view view-title="My Title" class="flex-wrapper" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <div class="flex-head"> ... </div>
    <div class="flex-body flex-1"> ... </div>
    <div class="flex-foot"> ... </div>
</ion-view>
```

The SCSS, using Ionic's mixins, looks something like this:

```
.flex-wrapper {
    @include display-flex;
    @include flex-direction(column);
    ...
}

.flex-1 {
    @include flex(1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

actually i am using the version Ionic 2.0.0 i resolve with this code

```
<ion-fixed class="fixed">
 <button fab fab-right fab-bottom>
   ${{ totalPrice }}
 </button>
</ion-fixed>
```

in your File Scss

```
.fixed {
 bottom: 50px;
 right: 10px;
}
```