# Ionic | JavaScript | CSS: Fixed Footer For Drag & Drop

Tags: css, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop, overflow, css-position

#### Creating a Footer to Drag Items Into ( In Ionic )

I've been very active without any solution to my requirements. I've checked out the following links [ and many others ] in hopes to find any tactic to help me achieve this.

[How to scroll with ionic and have fixed content above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967780/how-to-scroll-with-ionic-and-have-fixed-content-above)

[Ionic framework and bottom fixed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165568/ionic-framework-and-bottom-fixed-content)

[position: fixed, bottom: 0 does not seem to work for ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279413/position-fixed-bottom-0-does-not-seem-to-work-for-ionic-app)

What I need is a footer to remain `position: fixed` **while** allowing `[draggable]` items within the `<ion-content />` element to be dragged into the footer. Here's some current implementation:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <!-- NG-REPEAT FOR ITEM IN ITEMS GOES HERE -->
    </ion-content>
    <listbuilder></listbuilder>
</ion-view>

.list-builder {
    background: $light;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 82px;
    box-shadow: 0px 16px 16px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 400ms all;

    &.active {
        height: 428px;
    }
    ... MORE STYLES

}
```

The issue is that because of the way Ionic implements scrolling (not scrolling, but moving content out of the way), I cannot get `<listbuilder />` to actually be `fixed` position at the bottom of `<ion-content />`.

So, **normally**, the solvent to this is putting the *"fixed"* element *outside* of `<ion-content />` and setting it to `position: [anything]` -- not unlike the `.bar-header` & `.bar-footer` components.

However, **this doesn't work with Drag & Drop because** the `overflow` on `<ion-content />` prevents the `[draggable]` element from passing over the  [ drop ] element.

To recap,

- If dropper element is inside of `<ion-content />`, dropper is not `fixed`.
- If dropper element is outside of `<ion-content />`, can't drag item over dropper.

So its sort of a `z-index` or `overflow` problem wrapped in an Ionic/`position: fixed` issue. But I've got to have a solution.

For what its worth, I'm using `ngDraggable` for the D&D actions, since it handles a lot for `touch` events, which are needed because of the absence of `drag` events on touch-devices.

This seems to be a hard requirement to fulfill because the dropper (`<listbuilder />`) must be in the footer and fixed.

Anyone have any ideas how I could possibly implement this in Ionic?

Much (much) Appreciation,

Cody